# SIM7020G nb-iot module interface with esp32

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, programming, esp32, c++

My code at the moment is to connect esp32 to MQTT server via wifi and its working completely fine.
The next step is to use sim7020G NB-IOT module to achieve the same connection but as I have never worked with Sim modules before, Can someone here give an overview of how this can be done? If any of you can share any tutorial or guide it can solve my problem. I couldn't find any tutorial on the internet.

Thanks

Comment: Ah, let me see. To get started, you can first talk to SIM8xx/9xx/7xxx using serial 9k6BdN81 AT commands. You might find my answer to the following newbie question helpful: Rpi3B+ Python Controlling Multiple SIM800 / SIM900 / SIM7600 Modules - tlfong01 Rpi SE, 2020jul04
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113992/using-3-sim800c-gsm-hat-on-1-raspberry-pi-3b/114038#114038. You can also search the Rpi SE forum for a couple of my other answers in SIM800. Cheers.